# Figuring out the steps in a Recursive Function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computability, recursion

I have the following recursive function:

$f(0) = 7$

$f(n+1) = f(n) + 6n + 1$ for all integers $n => 0 $

I know the answer is $f(n) = 3n^2 + 2n + 7$
I would like to know the steps to get to this result.

Comment: f(n) should be 3n^2 - 2n + 7 because f(1) = 8 but your f(1) = 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f(n+1)=f(n)+6n+1\Rightarrow f(n+1)-f(n)=6n+1$. From that we can have
$$f(1)-f(0)=6.0+1\\
f(2)-f(1)=6.1+1\\
f(3)-f(2)=6.2+1\\
---------\\
---------\\
---------\\
f(n)-f(n-1)=6.(n-1)+1$$ Adding all them up together we have
$$f(n)-f(0)=6\{0+1+2+........+(n-1)\}+n.1\\
f(n)-f(0)=6\frac{(n-1)(n-1+1)}{2}+n\\
f(n)=f(0)+6\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+n\\
f(n)=7+3n^2-3n+n\\
f(n)=3n^2-2n+7$$

Answer (score 0):

Write

$f(n) = f(n) - f(n-1) + f(n-1) - f(n-2) + ... + f(1) - f(0) + f(0)$
$ = 6(n-1) + 1 + + 6(n -2) + 1 + ... + 6*0 + 1 + 7 $

$= 6*(n-1)*n/2 + n + 7 $

$= 3n(n - 1) + n + 7 $

$= 3n^2 - 2n + 7$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
f(n)&= f(n-1)+6(n-1)+1\\
&=f(n-2)+6(n-2)+1+6(n-1)+1\\
&=f(n-2)+6(2n-2-1)+2\\
&=f(n-3)+6(n-3)+1+6(2n-2-1)+2\\
&=f(n-3)+6(3n-3-2-1)\\
&=\vdots\\
&=f(0)+6(n\cdot n-\Sigma_{i=1}^ni)+n\\
&=7+6(n^2-\frac{n(n+1)}{2})+n\\
&=3n^2-2n+7
\end{align}